# I can't push the Quick Release in - how do I fix it?

Tags: road-bike, quick-release

I have a Polygon bike at home and I have recently removed the rear wheel.

I had reinstalled the wheel but the Quick Release (QR) (?) but I can't seem to push it back no matter how much strength I use.

Comment: Can you please clarify what isn't working with the QR?  Did you remove the skewer from the axle?  Or are you having problems flipping over the QR's lever once its threadded hand-tight?

Comment: Are you able to "push it back" with wheel taken off tke bike? I suppose you screwed it too tight. There must be some clearance on QR to be able to "lock" it.

Comment: If you're talking about the lever that you push in to tighten, you need to adjust the thumb nut on the other side to give it the right amount of "slack".  If adjusted properly the lever should be difficult to push in all the way, but not impossible.

Comment: (The current quick release scheme is a bit of an anachronism.  Before "lawyer lips" simply swinging the lever out was enough to free the wheel, so there was usually no need to adjust it.  Since "lawyer lips" were introduced, however, the functionality of the design has been negatively impacted, but no one has come forward with a better one.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks sure they have come up with a better one.  Thru axles are so much nicer.  The sooner QR's are consigned to history the better.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks: The QR is not the problem. The problem lies with the increasing number of people who can't operate them properly. Lawyer lips are just the industry's safeguard against uneducated suing mis-users but they add another category of misuse. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Loosen the nut on the other side to the cam / lever.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Jdoh. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're answering see [answer] also.

Comment: What was wrong with my answer? I've read the 'How to Answer' but can't see how I didn't follow best practice.

Comment: Firstly, your answer is most likely the solution to the OP's problem. My welcome message to you is the same welcome I give every new member, when we can see that they haven't taken the tour, and aren't an experienced SE user. The bit about how to answer is because your answer is very short, and actually incomplete. Imagine a complete bicycle newbie reading this - a complete answer might explain that both sides of the QR can be undone, or loosened, so the the mechanism has room to move. It would have been voted down if there was something wrong with it. With more explanation it will be upvoted.

Comment: And I should mention, such a welcome message is meant to help new members learn to use the site. Pleased to see you're here, and learning :-)